# Python while loop is skipped

Tags: python

I'm trying to make a countdown clock and when I run it the last while loop is skipped and the loop exits completely. What could be the problem?

```
def countdown():
    print("Give the time for the countdown separated by a space.")
    time.sleep(0.3)
    print("If none just type in 00")
    hours_time = int(input("Hours:"))
    min_time = int(input("Minutes:"))
    sec_time = int(input("Seconds:"))
    print("Countdown will run for:{}Hr {}min {}sec".format(hours_time, min_time, sec_time))
    while (sec_time != 00):
        print("{}Hr {}min {}sec".format(hours_time, min_time, sec_time))
        time.sleep(1)
        sec_time = sec_time - 1
        while (min_time != 00 and sec_time == 00):
            print("{}Hr {}min 00sec".format(hours_time, min_time))
            time.sleep(1)
            min_time = min_time - 1
            sec_time = sec_time + 59
            while (hours_time != 00 and min_time == 00 and sec_time == 00):
                print("{}Hr 00min 00sec".format(hours_time))
                time.sleep(1)
                hours_time = hours_time - 1
                min_time = min_time + 59
                sec_time = sec_time + 59

countdown()
```

Comment: ``sec_time == 00`` cannot be true in the innermost loop. The containing loop already checks ``sec_time == 00``, *then* does ``sec_time = sec_time + 59`` – meaning ``sec_time`` is ``59`` before the innermost loop is entered.

Answer (score 1):

You only need one `while` loop. Decrease the seconds by 1 each time, and if it goes below zero, then adjust minutes accordingly, and similarly regarding hours:

```
    while sec_time != 0 or min_time != 0 or hours_time != 0:
        print("{}Hr {}min {}sec".format(hours_time, min_time, sec_time))
        time.sleep(1)
        sec_time -= 1
        if sec_time < 0:
            sec_time += 60
            min_time -= 1
            if min_time < 0:
                min_time += 60
                hours_time -= 1
```

Answer (score 1):

This uses format strings to make your time values have leading zeros:

```
seconds = (hours_time*60 + min_time)*60 + sec_time
while seconds != 0:
    m, s = divmod(seconds, 60)
    h, m = divmod(m, 60)
    print("{0:02d}Hr {1:02d}min {2:02d}sec".format(h,m,s))
    time.sleep(1)
    seconds = seconds - 1
```